# How do I get the path of the Explorer window in 19.10?

Tags: nautilus, 19.10, paths

If I open the default Explorer window and navigate to a folder how can I copy/paste the path? All the solutions I can find seem to rely on deprecated tools like [Ubuntu Tweak](https://github.com/tualatrix/ubuntu-tweak).

Comment: Usually the address bar will give you the absolute path. You may have to click around and figure it out, I was unaware that windows explorer had been ported to default Ubuntu. Maybe you should find out exactly which you're using and then you'd get better answers specific to that app - which distribution are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to copy current path in nautilus file explorer**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will select the entire path, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to clipboard

Quick : Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, hit <kbd>L</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. Done

[image]

Comment: I'm amazed by this UX - how is this supposed to be 'discoverable'?

Comment: @parsley72 find all keyboard shortcuts in the menu item 'keyboard shortcuts'

Comment: @parsley72 CTRL+L is a common shortcut for selecting the address in a browser. It's true for Google, Firefox, and if I recall correctly, Opera as well (did you know that?). So it makes sense that CTRL+L selects the address in a file browser.